# One query per each entity

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, elasticsearch

Imagine we have an ArrayCollection, containing several Doctrine Entities instance of Country. Also imagine that my method 'getName()' is, in fact, a one to many relation with several languages ( A2lixTranslation support )...

The point is that this ArrayCollection is built from ElasticSearch service, so when I retrieve all these entities, iterate them and print their name, is just an extra query for every category.

I don't really know how to manage this situation, so 150 extra queries is not mainainable...

### Example Implementation

```
$countries = // ArrayCollection of Countries, returned by any mapping system.
foreach ($countries as $country) {

    /**
     * As name is an entity, uses lazy loading in every iteration
     * Because I get collection as it comes, I would like to retrieve
     *   all names in one query. I thought about perform a DQL with a join
     *   of all countries and their names, so Doctrine will catch'em all
     *   but only catch my query and results, and do not identify retrieved
     *   results with my collection, so is not working...
     */
    $name = $country->getName();
    echo $name;
}

// Could be nice do something like this...

$countries = // ArrayCollection of Countries, returned by any mapping system.
$queryBuilder = $this
    ->getDoctrine()
    ->getRepository('ProjectCoreBundle:Country')
    ->createQueryBuilder('c');

/**
 * This query result should only add Cache with results
 */
$queryBuilder
    ->select('c','t')
    ->innerJoin('c.countryName','cn','WITH','c.id = cn.Country')
    ->getQuery()
    ->getResult();        

foreach ($countries as $country) {

    /**
     * At this poing, as Name relation entity is already loaded and cached
     *   lazy load will simply return object ( Any query is performed )
     */
    $name = $country->getName();
    echo $name;
}
```

Comment: Do you have some code or pseudo-code of what your are trying to accomplish ? It would help to understand your problem.

Comment: You want to replace your original query with one that joins the name relation.  That way you will get everything you need on one gulp.  Of course you might be surprised at how efficient these little lazy loading queries can be.  After you get it working try running some bench marks.  Could be that those extra queries won't have much impact at all due to caching.

Comment: @cerad Thanks. The point is that elasticSearch is actually doing this query, so at the moment is intouchable. And 600 query calls are too much...

Comment: Have you checked the elastic search documentation?  I don't use it myself but I would not be surprised if there is an eager loading setting.  I have an import process which kicks off tens of thousands of tiny queries.  Makes almost no difference in total run time.  Surprised the heck out of me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, in fact I found already the best way to retrieve translations with entities.
Must be done overwriting ElasticSearch DataTransformer.

Answer (score 1):

I recommend taking a look at the Multi Search API endpoint in Elasticsearch: http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/reference/api/multi-search/.  It will allow you to prepare a single web request with multiple queries; ES will return the same number of responses as the number of queries in the requests. It really shaves down the network communication time.

I think the alternative is to restructure your code/data/thinking to allow you to perform a single query to get all the information your looking for, but I don't think there's enough information to dig deeper here.